# How to write email configuration in jenkins pipeline to send different set of information for build success and build failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have pipeline which will trigger from SCM. I want to capture most of the information about what went wrong if build fails and needed information if build succeed. All the captured info i will be using it in mail body(As detail as possible). I want to know how to capture those info and Do i need to use try catch or is there any other way?

Could anyone help me with the solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in the scripted pipeline.
Certainly, you need to use try/catch/finally as the sending email step needs to run no matter build pass or fail; you need to catch the exception so that you can take useful information out of it and then finally run the send email step.

At a high level, it will look like this

```
    try {
        // put your stages/logic here
    } catch (ex) {
        // get exception details ex.message etc
        throw ex
    } finally {
        // put the email step
    }
```